# Can time be controlled with Siddhis?

Tags: time, siddhi

There are **Siddhis** for almost everything: teleportation, creating things out of nothing, and just controlling matter generally at will.

But is there a Siddhi for controlling time? Like speeding up or slowing down time, or going into the future or past?

Comment: In uddav geeta there are 18 siddhi that approksha gnani can acquire.. but this going to past is not allowed, there will be limit in each siddhi based capacity of the person acquiring the siddhi

Comment: There is no question of 'GOING' to future or past. You can however 'SEE' the future or past. Kala Chakra is Eka Dik - Time moves in one direction only. 'Tri-kāla-jñatvam' (knowledge of 3 times - past,present,future) is mentioned as one of the supernatural siddhis. Also, because of time-dilation - time is naturally sped-up/slowed-down in higher lokas, and one can visit them if enough tapas.

Comment: @ram - so one direction mean it goes in a cyclical manner (to account for kalpabheda) like let's say clockwise ?

Comment: @Carmensandiego, no it only goes forward. the yugas repeat, not time. what does cyclical even mean ? does it mean the past did not happen when circle completes.. no, it can't be like that. It is an infinite line, where many events repeat, with differing periods/frequencies

Comment: @ram - i am referring to the events that transpire . Arent they repeating in different Kalpas with minor variations,  and isn't that why Puranas have variations in storylines?

Comment: @Carmensandiego, yes events definitely do repeat. but the concept of 'time repeating in a cycle' does not make sense. for e.g. i woke up, ate, and slept today. i did it yesterday, and also tomorrow, hopefully :). so the events repeat. but yesterday will always exist in memory (until memory fades of course). That's why they say Brahma created ('yatha purvam akalpayat') - he created as it was before. which means 'before' always existed i.e. a infinite number of creations.

Comment: @ram - thank you. Got it

Comment: I have read that in the Gyangunj the Siddhas there can stop time, slow its flow.

Answer (score 1):

Really sorry, for not referencing anything because what you are asking cannot be concluded by a reference link or a sloka. Though every scripture by any rishi, in India, tells us the same thing.

If it was really possible to reference such thing, then no rishi would have wrote any text, although, they must had gave us some experiments.

And yes, this questions requires experiments not just a textual information.

In my personal experience, not only me, whosoever takes meditation as important as breathing.
has reported, time is constant/still/infinite, mind is the device which travels through it.

So, can we control time is wrong question, Can we control mind? should be the questions.

And absolutely yes, we can control the mind (and it is always a personal experience no other being can tell you this).
And once the mind is controlled, time is also controlled as a complement.

**Adding source:**
As per the story of Dhurava in Vishnu Purana, when he was in the Intense tapasya, and when lord vishnu met him.
ref: [Story of Dhruva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhruva)
The time of meeting of Dhruva and Vishnu is that experience, which cannot be written, that is why we write lord vishnu instead, just to full fill the gap. Vishnu is that experience, in case of Dhruva.

Also, as per Geeta, when Krishna stopped the time, answers the same thing.

Comment: How is time related to the mind?

Comment: @Wikash_ Time is not related to mind directly, but mind senses the time, Changes in physical reality Happens in our mind in an order or in a periodic way hence it seems time is moving. But actually things are changing, and what is witnessing the changes? Absolutely The Mind. This is all i can explain. thank you.

Comment: If the things which are you looking is not available in scriptures/shastras, you can site works of Gurus or experience of Yogis :)

Answer (score 0):

There was saint name DIPA MA.
her book mentions all supernatural powers she had. (Even bending time)

Dipa Ma: The Life and Legacy of a Buddhist Master https://amzn.eu/d/a3cFxdU

In that there is a story where. She SQUEEZED SPACE -TIME TO REACH A PLACE EARLY.

ALSO SHE SAID ....IN HER OWN WORDS that she went back mind moments and mind moments...to go back to BUDDHA TIME and listen those discourses personally....

The book vishudimagga (Buddhist book available free in google ,,,11K inr in Amazon)
Tell how to go back in time and future.

U can read dipa ma book or this article to confirm that she mastered bending space-time continum.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.lionsroar.com/mother-of-light-the-inspiring-story-of-dipa-ma/amp/

Comment: How is this possible? In Hinduism time only moves forward. The wheel of time moves only in one direction.